# How to find a matching element in a list and map it in as an Scala API method?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

Is there a method to do the following without doing both methods: `find` and `map`?

```
val l = 0 to 3
l.find(_ * 33 % 2 == 0).map(_ * 33) // returns Some(66)
```

Comment: Why do you want a single method to do this? Is it curiosity or is there a deeper reason?

Comment: Mostly curiosity, but it is an operation that I have done a few times so I was going to make a function to do it.  I assumed it was part of the library, but couldn't figure out where.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

How about using collect?

```
// Returns List(66)
List(1, 2, 3) collect { case i if (i * 33 % 2 == 0) => i * 33 }
```

However that will return *all* matches and not just the first one.

The better answer would have been, based on Scala 2.9:

```
// Returns Some(66)
List(1, 2, 3) collectFirst { case i if (i * 33 % 2 == 0) => i * 33 }
```

The solution suggested in the comments to append a `head` to get a Scala 2.8 version of that is not very efficient, I'm afraid. Perhaps in that case I would stick to your own code. In any case, in order to make sure it returns an option, you should not call `head`, but `headOption`.

```
// Returns Some(66)
List(1, 2, 3) collect { case i if (i * 33 % 2 == 0) => i * 33 } headOption
```

Comment: `collect` will return multiple matches, while `find` returns just one.

Comment: Scala 2.9 adds a `collectFirst` method. Otherwise, as Daniel's comment is alluding to, you will need to use `headOption` in addition to `collect` to get the same type and behaviour as the original example.

Comment: collect will traverse the entire list. if you're on 2.8 and can't use collectFirst, you can do myList.view.collect(...).headOption. by using a view, you avoid traversing the whole list.

Comment: The problem with it is that the operation must be executed twice because there is no way to reuse intermediate result from `guard`

Comment: you're calculating `i*33` twice in each case. Is that possible to do once?

Answer (score 22):

If you don't want to do your `map()` operation multiple times (for instance if it's an expensive DB lookup) you can do this:

`l.view.map(_ * 33).find(_ % 2 == 0)`

The `view` makes the collection lazy, so the number of `map()` operations is minimized.

Comment: I think this is the most correct answer to this question. The others are useless in most cases because the operation must be executed twice.

Comment: THANKS! exactly what I wanted never heard of this views before (but used somethi,ng like that with Java/Guava in the past)!

Answer (score 6):

Hey look, it's my little buddy `findMap` again!

```
/**
 * Finds the first element in the list that satisfies the partial function, then 
 * maps it through the function.
 */
def findMap[A,B](in: Traversable[A])(f: PartialFunction[A,B]): Option[B] = {
  in.find(f.isDefinedAt(_)).map(f(_))
}
```

Note that, unlike in the accepted answer, but like the `collectFirst` method mentioned in one of its comments, this guy stops as soon as he finds a matching element.

Comment: `Traversable` already defines the method `collectFirst` which does exactly what your `findMap` does.

Answer (score -1):

This can do it, but it would be easier if you tell what you're really trying to achieve:

```
l.flatMap(n => if (n * 33 % 2 == 0) Some(n * 33) else None).headOption
```

Comment: this traverses the entire list