# Scala apply function on list elements to return a value

Tags: scala, list, function

I have found this answer in the forum earlier to a question I have been looking for, [How to find a matching element in a list and map it in as an Scala API method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479227/how-to-find-a-matching-element-in-a-list-and-map-it-in-as-an-scala-api-method)

```
// Returns Some(66)
List(1, 2, 3) collectFirst { case i if (i * 33 % 2 == 0) => i * 33 }
```

Now if I am replacing the if clause with a function

```
// 
List(1, 2, 3) collectFirst { case i if ( test(i) > 0) => test(i) }
```

this works but test() will be evaluated twice. Is there a better solution to apply a function to a list and return a result when a condition is met (not having to go through all elements and not havong to call the function twice (for evaluation and for returning the value.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, perhaps?
Breaking it into two separate operations lets you save/reuse intermediate results.

```
List(1,2,3).iterator.map(test).find(_ > 0)
```

Comment: why `.iterator`?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella iterators are lazy, so, this way it will only call `test` as many times as it needs to before it returns a positive result for the first time. 
Without `.iterator`, `test` would get applied to _all_ elements of the list first, before `.find` condition would start getting evaluated. So, if a list has 1000 elements, and `test` returns a positive value on the first of them, there will be 10000 invocations without `.iterator`, but only one with it.

Comment: Thanks so much to both of you. This helps a lot. The wrapper below is a good pattern as well making it hard for me to chose from :-)

Comment: Meanwhile I was able to read through the docs and found Stream which is a lazy list and came up with this solution: 

Stream(1,2,3).map(test).find(_ > 0)

Comment: @Sven Iterators are more memory-friendly  than streams. If you do not _already_ have a list, like in your example, it doesn't matter one way or another, but if the `List` is, for example, given to the function as an argument, copying it to a `Stream` before traversing is more expensive, than simply going through the `iterator`.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your function in a custom extractor:

```
def test(i: Int): Int = i - 1

object Test {
  def unapply(i: Int): Option[Int] = Some(test(i))
}

scala> List(1, 10, 20) collectFirst { case Test(i) if i > 0 => i }
res0: Option[Int] = Some(9)
```

You can generalize this solution and make a class for that kind of extractors:

```
case class Extract[T, U](f: T => U) {
  def unapply(t: T): Option[U] = Some(f(t))
}

scala> val Test2 = Extract(test)
Test2: Extract[Int,Int] = Extract($$Lambda$1326/1843609566@69c33ea2)

scala> List(1, 10, 20) collectFirst { case Test2(i) if i > 0 => i }
res1: Option[Int] = Some(9)
```

You can also wrap the guard into the extractor as well:

```
case class ExtractWithGuard[T, U](f: T => U)(pred: U => Boolean) {
  def unapply(t: T): Option[U] = {
    val u = f(t)
    if (pred(u)) Some(u)
    else None
  }
}

scala> val Test3 = ExtractWithGuard(test)(_ > 0)
Test3: ExtractWithGuard[Int,Int] = ExtractWithGuard($$Lambda$1327/391731126@591a4d25)

scala> List(1, 10, 20) collectFirst { case Test3(i) => i }
res2: Option[Int] = Some(9)
```

Comment: I like this , too !